# Get Access Token from Refresh Token using cURL

Tags: php, api

I am trying to get generate a token using curl. I am new to API generating tokens

```
<?php
    $username = '12345678'; //Fill with your app username Key
    $password = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // Fill with your app passowrd
    $headers = ['application/x-www-form-urlencoded'];
    $url = 'https://api.equitybankgroup.com/v1/token';
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
     $credentials = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'; //API Key
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic '.$credentials));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $result;
    curl_close($curl);

?>
```

I have tried posting in postman, and it generating well.

How do generate a token using the above code
[image]

Comment: You can generate PHP code of your request, useing postman "Code" generator, bellow "Send Save" button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the request type option for the request.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$vars);  //Post Fields
```